# Saparate array data with comma

Tags: php, arrays

I have an function that return an array

```
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "22"
    [1]=>
    string(9) "Plantroom"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "22"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "dfdf"
  }
}
```

sometime my array have one object or multiple .

```
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "23"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "sec"
  }
}
```

now I want to show my array data by comma separated.

like

for first array => Plantroom,dfdf

for second  array =>sec

I am using this code but not work

my function

```
function area_name($game_id)
{
    include_once('Model/Game.php');
    $c2 = new Game();

    $cd2 = $c2->Select_area($game_id);


return $cd2;

}
```

and call my function as

```
implode(", ", area_name($cd[$i][0]))
```

But my output show text Array

Answer (score 1):

Because `area_name()` is not just returning an array, its returning an array of arrays. `implode()` will join the elements of the array that `area_name()` returns assuming they are strings, but those elements are also arrays and as such they are stringified to text `"Array"`.

To obtain the desired output from `implode()` you would have to first generate an array with only the values you want from the structure returned by `area_name()`.

For instance:

```
$data = array_map(function ($a) { return $a[1]; }, area_name($cd[$i][0]));
echo implode(', ', $data);
```